# curl result pick 1 randomly

Tags: php, curl, random, shuffle

i'm new to php, i have this code, i need to know how to get only 1 random result from this code.
Thanks

```
Array ( [0] => Hobby Lobby [1] => Zendaya [2] => Iggy Azalea [3] => Costa Rica vs Greece [4] => WWE [5] => The Leftovers [6] => Robin Thicke [7] => France Vs Nigeria [8] => Philip Lutzenkirchen [9] => Jason Kidd )
```

.

```
}

function my_get_google_hot_trend($country_code) {
    $result = array(
        'data' => array(),
        'error' => ''
    );


    $keywords = $match[1];

    $result['data'] = $keywords;
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Pls Help me in getting the result as I Need...

Comment: Did you put any effort into solving this yourself? Do a quick web search? Read the relevant PHP manual pages? _Anything_?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Didn't test, but this should work;

$array[rand(0,9)];